# How to Clear variables from JTextFields without closing whole program?

Tags: java, swing, text-files, writefile

I have created a text file in which to store some variables which are taken from text fields. But in order to submit new variables to this text file, I need to close my program and reopen it. The `dispose();` command closes the `JFrame` taking me to my main menu but upon opening the menu again and submitting different values, the values from the previous time have been resubmitted.  Is there a simple way to amend this?

Here is my write to .txt code:

```
public class writeto {

static String data = AddProperty.inputdata;
BufferedWriter out;

public writeto(){
        try{
            out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("writeto.txt", true));

            out.write(data);

            out.newLine();

            out.close();

        }catch(IOException e){

            System.out.println("you have an error" + e);
        }
    }
}
```

and where the method is called in my `addproperty` class

```
        submitproperty.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
              housenumber1 = houseNumber.getText();
              streetname1 = streetName.getText();
              town1 = town.getText();
              postcode1 = postcode.getText();
              beds1 = beds.getText();
              price1 = price.getText();
              type1 = type.getText();

            inputdata = housenumber1 + " " + streetname1 + " " + town1 + " " + 

            postcode1 +" " + beds1 + " " + price1 + " " + type1;

             writeto write = new writeto();
             dispose();
            }
       });
    }
```

Comment: Basically a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6018678/clearing-jtextfields-to-write-multiple-data-to-txt-file/6018954#6018954 - the answer is the same (look at my answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would benefit greatly from using a database as opposed to a text file.  Further your question displays a fundamental lack of knowledge of not only Swing, but basic CRUD (Create, Read, Update, Delete) functionality.

To answer your question you can clear your text field with textField1.setText("");

I would read up on using a database for storing data.  It will make life much easier for you.

Comment: For this particular project it has been requested in the criteria that writing to a text file is required as opposed to a database. Although i will be sure to try .setText("") as way of clearing the textfields. Thank you for pointing out my fundamental lack of knowledge :)

Comment: I apologize, I didn't meant to make you feel inadequate, we were all in your shoes at one point in our careers.  I am sorry that you are constrained to using a text file, that really sucks.  It can become difficult and expensive to fetch existing records.

Answer (score 3):

From your menu you should always create a *new* JFrame with *new* widgets (like text fields). A *new* text field has no content, if you show a text field again, it will still display it's previous content.

---

Additional remarks:

- Please use standard naming conventions - not only when you show code to others. In your case: class names shall start with a capital letter, camel-case notation is preferred (`writeto -> WriteTo`)
- The `writeto` class abuses the constructor. The code in your constructor does not *create* an `writeto` object but dumps some strings to a file. Put this kind of code to a method, not to a constructor.
- The `BufferedWriter` will not be closed if an exception occurs. Look around at stackoverflow, a lot of questions/answers show the correct io-closeing pattern
- disposing the jframe is a risk - the code is executed after pressing a button (correct?), inside a method on a button that is displayed on the frame (correct?). In that case the button may be disposed while a method on the button object is still executed.. Try `setVisible(false)` if you just want to hide the JFrame (like "close the dialog")